# jQuery - Get cell values and update cell values with result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple jQuery function that will grab the values of some input fields from 2 cells from a table and then perform some simple math to work out the difference, then update another cell value with the difference.

Here's my function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Calculate').click(function(){

    var nextYearTotal = $("#textfield6").text();
    var lastYearTotal = $("#textfield1").text();

    nextYearTotal = Number(nextYearTotal);
    lastYearTotal = Number(lastYearTotal);

    var updatedTotal = nextYearTotal - lastYearTotal;

    $('#textfield7').html(updatedTotal);
    });
});
```

No matter what the values in the textfield6 and textfield1 input fields are I'm getting "0" as the result in the textfield7 cell.

I'm new to jQuery - would greatly appreciate it if someone can point out my error. This function is called when I click a button in a row of the table.

Comment: Are they inputs? if so `val()` not `text()`

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with some sample HTML + this jQuery?

Comment: Is $('#textfield7') a table cell or an actual input text field?

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the HTML - didn't realise it would be the issue here. Thanks to Alex K. for pointing this out - once I changed to val() instead of text() it worked immediately. I should have mentioned these were input fields - will include html next time. Thanks Alex K for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the value not the text.

```
var nextYearTotal = Number($("#textfield6").val());
var lastYearTotal = Number($("#textfield1").val());
```

See working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dezzS/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Calculate').click(function() {
        var nextYearTotal = Number($("#textfield6").val());
        var lastYearTotal = Number($("#textfield1").val());

        var updatedTotal = nextYearTotal - lastYearTotal;

        $('#textfield7').html(updatedTotal);
    });
});​
```

**Edit**
Comments on the original post clarified that the source fields are inputs but the target field is just a cell.

Based on the comments I updated the DEMO and code for completness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Calculate').click(function(){

    var nextYearTotal = parseFloat($("#textfield6").text());
    var lastYearTotal = parseFloat($("#textfield1").text());

    var updatedTotal = nextYearTotal - lastYearTotal;
    if (!(isNaN(updatedTotal)))
         $('#textfield7').html(updatedTotal);
    });
});
```

Should work supposing you have 3 `<td>`'s with the ID's `"textfield1"`, `"textfield6"`,`"textfield7"` and a button or link with `id="Calculate"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#Calculate').click(function(){

var nextYearTotal = $("#textfield6").val();
var lastYearTotal = $("#textfield1").val();

nextYearTotal = Number(nextYearTotal);
lastYearTotal = Number(lastYearTotal);

var updatedTotal = nextYearTotal - lastYearTotal;

$('#textfield7').html(updatedTotal);
});
});
```